TV series where child is sucked up by a vacuum cleaner
I remember watching this around 2016 on live tv, although the episode/movie looked older.
It consisted of a spoiled child acting up and then getting sucked up by a vacuum cleaner.
I also think I remember seeing other episodes of this where similar stuff happened. I think it was animated and I remember the characters looking kind of like cabbage patch kids, not sure if I'm just confusing thing though.
The only thing I'm sure about is the kid being sucked by a vacuum.

Possibly Hush, Season 4 ep. 18 of Tales from the Darkside, as described in this answer.
The episode was based on a short story, Hush!,  by Zenna Henderson. In both, the vacuum cleaner was a noise-eating machine (based on an actual vacuum cleaner) that the child created and/or activated. I haven't seen the episode or found a description of what happened to the kid, but in the story,

 the noise eater sucked the life out of him, ironically making a sound like a drinking straw in a glass, as his horrified babysitter watched.

